# Multiple counts with one SQL query

Tags: sql

I need to do a count of the number of procedures in a table which are filtered on a product code using a single query, but returning the separate counts in the same column. The data looks like this

```
prod_id prod_code
1 0A
2 0A
3 0B
4 0A
5 0B
6 0B
```

From the dataset above, the total count for 0A and 0B is 3 and 3 respectively. This is what I want after the count

```
prod_code count prod_name
0A 3 Product A
0B 3 Product B
```

I am aware that one way to do multiple counts using a single query is like so. However, this gives me separate columns for the count of each product. How can I get them to be in the same column?

```
select sum(case when proc_code LIKE '0A' then 1 else 0 end) as count1
,sum(case when proc_code LIKE '0B' then 1 else 0 end) as count2
from products
```

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.  `COUNT()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
select prod_code, count(prod_code)
from products
group by prod_code
```

Comment: Thanks Alex - that was a really trivial ask. I think the challenge in my case though is that I want to also add the name of the product to the output (see op). These are hard-coded names not values within a column so I can't add them to the group by. Would this be accomplished via a case statement perhaps? Problem solved:

Select case when products.prod_id = '0A' then 'Product A' 
when products.prod_id = '0B' then 'Product B' end as [Product_Name]
,count(products.prod_id) as [Count]
from products 
where products.prod_id in ('0A', '0B')
group by products.prod_id

Comment: @EdwardChau how do you know 0A is Product A. Do you just remove `0` and put `Product` instead from prod_code?

Comment: I know what the corresponding product codes are a priori. What if I have a situation where multiple product codes correspond to Product A. I think the group by clause works fine if it is just one code per product, but I don't think I will get the intended result if there are multiple codes. 

How would I deal with that scenario?